# Type safety warning when casting to generic type

Tags: java, generics

(*When researching this, all I found were SO posts and websites saying you cannot simply cast to a generic type due to type erasure, I found nothing on point.*)

Can someone explain to me why Eclipse prompts me with this warning?

```
public <T> T getFromBag(String key, Class<T> clazz) {
        Object val = null;
        T typeCastValue = null;

        if (commonDataBag.containsKey(key)) {
            val = commonDataBag.get(key);
            typeCastValue = clazz.cast(val);
        }
        return typeCastValue;
    }
```

Usage:

```
Map<String, Foo> stuff= myService().<Map>getFromBag(key, Map.class);
```

Warning:

```
Type safety: The expression of type Map needs unchecked conversion to conform to Map<String,Foo>
```

Comment: Yeah, this is basically inevitable.  You can call `getFromBag(key, Map.class)` but you can't use generics to enforce that the result will be a `Map<String, Foo>` instead of another kind of `Map`.

Comment: `Map.class` doesn't say which kind of `Map` it is, and there's no such thing as `Map<String, Foo>.class`.

Answer (score 2):

> Can someone explain to me why Eclipse prompts me with this warning?

In `myService().<Map>getFromBag(key, Map.class)`, you provide an explicit type witness (`<Map>`) for the type variable `T`. Therefore, the return type of the call is `T`, which is `Map`. Then you assign that (of type `Map`) to type `Map<String, Foo>`, which is an unchecked implicit conversion from a raw type to a parameterized type.

Answer (score 0):

Your return value is of class HashMap, there is not way to be sure that it's HashMap, so you get a warning.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine if you have code like this:

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("foo", "bar");
commonDataBag.put("42", map);
```

Then you call:

```
Map<String, Foo> stuff= myService().<Map>getFromBag("42", Map.class);
Foo foo = stuff.get("foo");
```

At this point you'll get a classcastexception because your map doesn't contain `Foo` values, it contains `String` values.

This is what prompts the warning.